# How can I add autosave to a Note App with entities?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to learn how to make android apps so I followed a tutorial series on YouTube and I made a Note App. But I need to add autosave and I don't know how. I searched on YouTube and I tried everything and nothing works.
Here is the Playlist with the tutorials:
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLam6bY5NszYN6-a1wt7yRISWfmYPdkbMu

As I said before, I'm new to all of this, but I really want to make this app.

Comment: We will not follow links to tutorials.

Comment: And you should tell us at which moment or at which action the 'auto'save should be done. What is 'autosaving' to begin with you might explain.

Comment: Autosave should be done while you write. Idk how to explain.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "periodic work request" to auto-save your notes.
you can use this tutorial or other tutorial
[enter link description here](https://www.google.com/search?q=periodic%20request&sxsrf=ALiCzsa5cUTx869BzHAGQiGFvTMdNKx0Sw%3A1671282160905&ei=8L2dY4H3NumX9u8Pq6mv0A0&ved=0ahUKEwiBr5Sc24D8AhXpi_0HHavUC9oQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=periodic%20request&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoKCAAQRxDWBBCwA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFCkCFikCGCTC2gCcAF4AIABiwKIAYsCkgEDMi0xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:3b4201b2,vid:1VVir3-4hII)